# Laravel-how to upload image to cloudinary with queue?

Tags: laravel, cloudinary

I use laravel version 9. I want to upload image in Cloudinary but with laravel (job) queue. So It will upload image in background . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put the upload code inside a Laravel [Job](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#creating-jobs) and run the job asynchronously. Just make sure the job's timeout is enough to upload a large file.

Also (pretending you've installed the [Cloudinary Laravel package](https://github.com/cloudinary-labs/cloudinary-laravel)), you can use the `'async'=> true,` in the upload parameters to make the upload asynchronous. Then, once the upload is done, cloudinary servers will reach out the `notification_url` webhook with the file data

```
 (new UploadApi())->upload($url, [
            'cloud_name'    => '...',  
            'resource_type' => 'auto',
            'async'         => true,
            'notification_url' => route('your.webhook.route'),//when the upload is done
        ]);
```

For more infos about the picker's options, you can check their doc [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference)